# Errors when updating Redactor

Tags: upgrades

Folks:

I'm slowly working my way through a Craft3/Commerce2 upgrade. My current issue:

When updating redactor I receive multiple errors. I just want to be sure I'm on the right track.

Error 1:

`Cannot create cache directory /.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache`

`Cannot create cache directory /.composer/cache/repo/https---composer.craftcms.com/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache`

`Cannot create cache directory /.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache`

I assume the **vendor > composer** folder needs to be writable to make this work, correct?

Error 2:

`Package "craftcms/vue-asset" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.`

This seems straightforward but where do I find this? I figured as it seems to be part of Craft it would already be there.

Answer (score 1):

With update issues like this, you'll have to run `composer update` rather than using the CP update button. You can either SSH into your server to run `composer update` or update the files on your local computer and push the new files (they'll be in vendor > craftcms > redactor) to your server. Make sure you do a database backup before doing this. After doing this manual update, when you go to your Craft CP, you'll probably get a notice that Craft needs to make changes to your database, so just click ok or whatever it says.

If Composer says there's nothing to update, you'll need to edit your composer.json file. At the top of composer.json under "require" you'll see your Redactor plugin; edit the numbers to the version number you see in the Craft updates in your Control Panel, then run `composer update`.